# How to customize validation message position in login validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, jquery-ui, tooltip

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control"
        name="username" placeholder="Enter ID" required
        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter ID')"
        oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```

How to customize the Validation message position to the right of the textbox? Now it's coming below the textbox.

Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/vvfR5pelzeJAMM5LagC9?p=preview

Comment: There is another idea used in asp.net mvc with javascript. [Similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31187973/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-position-of-validation-message)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/85xwh/1/ here its is there..but when i try it on plunker its not working!

Answer (score 0):

Using of positions to the element for parent element use relative and use position absolute for tooltip. If possible show your demo code.

Comment: I have added plunker link..And sorry its for validation message and not for tooltip..I have edited

Comment: You can also try these boostrap form validation examples @ [demo link](http://formvalidation.io/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with jQuery dependent script.

```
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
        <textarea id="comments" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>​

<script>
    var createAllErrors = function() {
        var form = $( this ),
            errorList = $( "ul.errorMessages", form );

        var showAllErrorMessages = function() {
            errorList.empty();

            // Find all invalid fields within the form.
            var invalidFields = form.find( ":invalid" ).each( function( index, node ) {

                // Find the field's corresponding label
                var label = $( "label[for=" + node.id + "] "),
                    // Opera incorrectly does not fill the validationMessage property.
                    message = node.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.';

                errorList
                    .show()
                    .append( "<li><span>" + label.html() + "</span> " + message + "</li>" );
            });
        };

        // Support Safari
        form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            if ( this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity() ) {
                $( this ).find( ":invalid" ).first().focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        $( "input[type=submit], button:not([type=button])", form )
            .on( "click", showAllErrorMessages);

        $( "input", form ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
            var type = $( this ).attr( "type" );
            if ( /date|email|month|number|search|tel|text|time|url|week/.test ( type )
              && event.keyCode == 13 ) {
                showAllErrorMessages();
            }
        });
    };

    $( "form" ).each( createAllErrors );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that code..but still that validation message is coming below text box right? i need it in rightside of textbox?

Comment: Can you give some plunker link or some working demo?

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj <input type="text" style="text-align: right" />

Comment: I dont want the placeholder message to align right..I want the validation popup message to come in rightside

Comment: Try this one :  inlineMsg('name','You must enter your name.',2);

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the validation message position by adding this CSS code.

```
.form-control[required] {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    margin-left: 100px !important;
}
```